# Stopping alarms after the app is killed Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have a situation in my application. I am calling a service using an alarm. The alarm wakes up every 5 min and calls the service.

But it may so happen that the user might close my app and I am allowing the functionality of the service to work even if the user is not using my app.

To stop the service there are two ways either the user comes back to the app and presses a button which will cancel the alarm OR the second way is say after x time I want to stop the service i.e cancel the alarm from a broadcast receiver.

Now how can I do the second way ? When I tried to get reference of the AlarmManager it is giving me error of Null Pointer. (I am accessing this alarm manager from a broadcast receiver)

Can anyone give me suggestion on how to cancel repeating alarms from outside the activity context ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Show me some code and your logcat....

Comment: If you are going to use time to determine when to stop scheduling an alarm, you need to save the time in some place that will persist even when your app is not running, such as `SharedPreferences`. You can simply store the time the user started the alarms and check with each wakeup whether enough time has passed that you should cancel them.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop your service like this
`context.stopService(new Intent(context, YourService.class))`

Also in order to cancel the alarm you can do this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1253, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT| Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

I hope this might help you

Answer (score 0):

In your BroadcastReceiver try this:

```
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          context.stopService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
      }
```